# Why do we need to create loggers per class?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

Many forums and stackoverflow questions suggest that the recommended approach for creating loggers is to create them per class.

A quick look at the Log4j's  `Logger getLogger(String name)`  implementation suggests that, all the loggers are stored in a static map.

I wonder if we have thousands of classes in an application and a logger is defined in each class, wouldn't it cause memory/performance issues.

Alternatively, why cant we define some standard loggers (based on some functional criteria) in the application and have the developers use them in the classes. I understand that having a separate logger allows us to change its logging level, but I believe its not big issue if there are sufficient predefined loggers.

I looked at the questions [Is a logger per class or is a set of loggers that are accessed by the entire application perferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628677/is-a-logger-per-class-or-is-a-set-of-loggers-that-are-accessed-by-the-entire-app) and [Log4J: Strategies for creating Logger instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770076/log4j-strategies-for-creating-logger-instances)
but they dont seem to cover this topic.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to, it's just easier to manage. Loggers follow parent-child relationship. Children pretty much inherit everything from their parents. This way you can define very specific logging behavior or have it inherited generically.

> Alternatively, why cant we define some standard loggers (based on some
>   functional criteria) in the application and have the developers use
>   them in the classes. I understand that having a separate logger allows
>   us to change its logging level, but I believe it's not big issue if
>   there are sufficient predefined loggers.

This would require some pretty intense dependency injection to make those loggers available to every type, also potentially adding an extra dependency.

Comment: How about creating a custom logger class that contains all other categories as static members.                                 public class CustomLogger { 
 public final static Logger customlog = LoggerFactory.getLogger("customlog");
} </code> and we call CustomLogger.customlog.infor("");

Comment: @NareshVavilala What do you gain by doing that? You now have to do `CustomLogger.customlog.debug(..)` to log your message.

Comment: With this, I can limit the number of loggers used in the system, and reduce the number entries stored in the map managed by logging provider

Comment: @NareshVavilala The `Logger` instance are all managed by your logging framework. You can still do `LoggerFactory.getLogger("random");` in some class not called `random`. By keeping the `private static` field in each class just makes it easier to use internally.

Comment: I understand that. But there is no way to track the logger names if we use names other than class names. Having all the loggers declared in a separate class makes the application classes independent of logging code. Once we have this setup we can use custom loggers just like 'System.out' and 'System.err'

Comment: @NareshVavilala (You can use backticks `\`` for code fragments.) The only logging code you should have is `debug(..)`, `info(..)`, and others. And that code should very much be dependent on the class that uses it (and vice versa). The fact is, you don't need your custom class to get a reference to another logger. `LoggerFactory.getLogger(..)` gives you access to ALL loggers managed by your library. Your configuration is the only access point.